# Looping through jQuery object and getting data value

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have a jQuery object which I get via code such as this:

```
var elements = $('#all_cats_holder div.wSelect-option-selected').detach();
```

The code it gets will be something such as:

```
<div class="wSelect-option wSelect-option-selected"><div class="wSelect-option-value" data-val="2">Some stupid cat #2</div></div>
<div class="wSelect-option wSelect-option-selected"><div class="wSelect-option-value" data-val="3">Some stupid cat #3</div></div>
<div class="wSelect-option wSelect-option-selected"><div class="wSelect-option-value" data-val="4">Some stupid cat #4</div></div>
```

Now I'm trying to loop through this data and get the value of `data-val` but I can't seem to get it to work.

My code:

```
var mr_val;

$.each(elements, function(index, el) {

    mr_val = el.data('val');

    alert(mr_val);            

});
```

I don't even get an alert at all.

Comment: That's because you're looping through the outer divs, which have no `data-val` attribute. You want to traverse to the child div, and then pull the attribute from that.

Comment: Those elements doesn't seem to match the class given in the selector, are you sure that's what you're getting.

Comment: @PatrickQ Ahh... that's probably it. Thanks.

Comment: @adeneo My bad. Updated.

Comment: Note that `el` inside the loop is **not** a jQuery object, and has no `data()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just make it an array with $.map

```
var mr_val = $.map(elements, function(el) {
    return $(el).find('[data-val]').data('val');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/94zm6/)

or with each

```
var mr_val;

$.each(elements, function(index, el) {

    mr_val = $(el).find('div').data('val');

    alert(mr_val);            

});
```